# Wait for specific DOM element (anchor) to be loaded before setting its visibility and text on a message listener condition

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to update a DOM element (specifically an anchor element with id `status_2`) when two strings are not equal to each other. I have the below script for my button pop up for my Firefox extension I'm developing.

```
var myString;

function setMyString() {
    myString = Math.random().toString();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    setMyString();
    document.getElementById("status_1").innerText = myString;
});

window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    if (event.source == window && event.data.type == 'broadcast') {
        setMyString();

        var otherString = event.data.data[0];
        console.log(otherString); // This works, but...

        // I want to be able to set the text for status_2 and make the element visible;
        // when the strings match; the element is an anchor/link element and it is
        // set as hidden in the corresponding CSS.
        //
        // These two fail with "not defined". The element can't be found.
        if (myString != otherString) {
            document.getElementById("status_2").innerText = otherString;
            document.getElementById("status_2").style.visibility = "visible";
        }

        setMyString();
    }
});
```

I have tried embedding the DOMContentLoaded listener within the message listener, but then the message listener doesn't work. How can I force the code in the message listener, to be forced to wait until the status_2 anchor element has DOM loaded. Thank you.